# What is the correct nomenclature for Glucuronyl C5-epimerase?

Tags: nomenclature, biochemistry, enzymes

I see people writing "Glucuronyl C5-epimerase", "Glucuronyl C-5-epimerase", "Glucuronyl-C-5-epimerase" and "Glucuronyl C5 epimerase", which one is correct? Is there a naming convention?

Comment: @basseur The question is very clear and concise. It is: ‘should enzyme names like the one above contain hyphens and should there be a hypen between C and 5?’ I think this is answerable and sufficiently on-topic (while it may be even more on topic on [biology.se]).

Comment: @Jan: You are right. I guess from my standpoint as a professional chemist I was too narrow-minded to see, that this is not as obvious as it seems to me. My bad.
I actually don't believe, this is a homework question, as it was flagged.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! I don't think this is homework, and I am reopening the question. Nevertheless, please see our [guidelines on how to ask nomenclature questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/3066/).

Answer (score 5):

I have not found this particular enzyme in *Enzyme Nomenclature.* However, following the [Recommendations of the Nomenclature Committee of the International Union of Biochemistry and Molecular Biology](http://www.sbcs.qmul.ac.uk/iubmb/enzyme/), the name should be **glucuronyl 5-epimerase.** See also this [sublist](http://www.sbcs.qmul.ac.uk/iubmb/enzyme/EC5/1/3/) for some analogous names of other epimerases.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Loong’s answer which includes the formally correct way to write it: if you wish to unambiguously indicate that a carbon atom is epimerised,<sup>[1]</sup> the only possible choices are those that leave **no space** between the symbol for carbon and the digit. Atoms are number-named by writing the element symbol directly followed by their number without hyphen or space. So the atom in question is C5, meaning we have a C5-epimerase.

---

**Note:**

[1]: Which is superfluous since carbon atoms are practically the only atoms ever epimerised.